# Master Detail Fast Reports

Tags: sql, delphi, relatório, fast-reports

Tenho um relatório em Fast Report de notas e duplicadas / boletos.

No data tenho 2 `DbxQuery`, nota e boletos. No boletos coloquei o master como notas, e utilizei como filtro no boletos o parâmetro nunota(numero da nota) apontando para o `DbxQuerynota`, e fiz um `select max(parcela)` no `DbxQuery` boleto.

Utilizei um sub-relatório, mas quando gero ele mostra por exemplo a nota 1, mas os boletos da nota 2, e na nota 3 os boletos da nota 4 e assim por diante, já tentei utilizar uma banda DetailData mas n funcionou tbm.

alguém tem uma dica!!

Comment: Posta o SQL que você fez amigo.

Comment: Cara no momento não tenho e um problema no serviço então sé segunda, mas é mais ou menos assim, no select principal cliente, nota itens,frete, etc e no "detail", tenho as parcelas, certo então uma nota com N itens, (5 por exemplo) poder ter 0 ou mais parcelas (tipo 30,60,90), então tenho uma tabela so para os vencimentos imaginemos "FatNota", onde a PK é a filial e o número da nota. ai no fast defino no select "detail" where nota = :nunota e filial = :Cdfil sendo estes parâmetros definidos no DbxQuery "detail" para "pegar" da Query "master"

Comment: Mais assim, o que nao funciona? Não aparece nada no relatório? Aparece as notas e duplicatas / boletos duplicados?

Comment: como disse acima, mostra a nota 1 mas os boletos da nota 2, compreende! mostra a nota 10 mas os boletos da nota 11 no detail...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depois de ter abandonado por um tempo esta questão consegui resolver,
como tinha uma query a qual pegava dados de 12 tabelas como, nota, itens, tamanhos, cor, funcionário, cliente cfop, faturamento etc,
resolvi fazer uma query separada para o faturamento.[image: data]
ai criei um subreport e coloquei no rodapé do grupo do meu master data principal[image: page1]
e no evento *OnBeforePrint* do GroupFooter1 adicionei via script o comando sql á query fat, passando como filtros dados do próprio relatório ja gerado como campo da filial ja impresso no cabeçalho.
 Depois foi so inserir os campo que eu queria no meu *subreport*, enfim acabou o meu problema de aparecerem os vencimentos da nota 2 na nota 1.